# Array is not setting values properly

Tags: java, arrays

The first 4 values are set properly in the new array. It has to do with something with my variable 'count' which is not being set properly. The goal of the program is to simply grab the even numbers, and put them in a new array.

I have added 4 to count as a test, and that seems to work perfectly but I dont think that is the issue here.

```
 int[] list = {8,5,4,11,12,2,1,3,10,6,7};

    int count = 0;
    int gr = 0;

    for(int n=0; n<list.length; n++)
    {
        if(list[n] % 2 == 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    int[] evn = new int[count];

    for(int k = 0; k<=count; k++)
    {
        if(list[k] % 2 == 0)
            evn[gr++] = list[k];
    }
 return evn;
```

Currently, the array prints "8,4,12,2,0,0" when it should print "8,4,12,2,10,6"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `count` is always less than the size of the array(`list.length`), so in the second for-loop you are never iterating till the end of the array.

Change your second for-loop to iterate till the end of the array as shown below :

```
for(int k = 0; k < list.length; k++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only traversing part of `list`, as stated in the `for` condition:

```
for(int k = 0; k<=count; k++)
               ^--here--^
```

This is because `count` has a lower value than the length of the original array. Change this condition to traverse the whole array:

```
for(int k = 0; k<list.length; k++)
```

Answer (score 0):

To traverse the whole `list` change the following:

```
 for(int k = 0; k<=count; k++)
```

To

```
 for(int k = 0; k<list.length; k++)
```